# Hamcrest and ScalaTest

Tags: unit-testing, scala, hamcrest

I found `Hamcrest` convenient to use with `JUnit`. Now I am going to use `ScalaTest`. I know I can use `Hamcrest` but I wonder if I really *should*. Does not `ScalaTest` provide similar functionality ? Is there any other Scala library for that purpose (matchers) ?

Do people use `Hamcrest` with `ScalaTest`?

Comment: I can't speak for this particular question, but: In my general experience, I find that Java libraries aiming to provide expressiveness are usually obviated by Scala libraries (or simply by Scala language features).

Answer (score 4):

As Michael said, you can use [ScalaTest's matchers](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers). Just make sure you extend [`Matchers`](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.2.4/#org.scalatest.Matchers) in your test class. They can very well replace functionality of Hamcrest, leverage Scala features and look more natural in Scala to me.

Here, you can compare Hamcrest and ScalaTest matchers on a few examples:

```
val x = "abc"
val y = 3
val list = new util.ArrayList(asList("x", "y", "z"))
val map = Map("k" -> "v")

// equality
assertThat(x, is("abc")) // Hamcrest
x shouldBe "abc"         // ScalaTest

// nullity
assertThat(x, is(notNullValue()))
x should not be null

// string matching
assertThat(x, startsWith("a"))
x should startWith("a")
x should fullyMatch regex "^a..$" // regex, no native support in Hamcrest AFAIK

// type check
assertThat("a", is(instanceOf[String](classOf[String])))
x shouldBe a [String]

// collection size
assertThat(list, hasSize(3))
list should have size 3

// collection contents
assertThat(list, contains("x", "y", "z"))
list should contain theSameElementsInOrderAs Seq("x", "y", "z")

// map contents
map should contain("k" -> "v") // no native support in Hamcrest

// combining matchers
assertThat(y, both(greaterThan(1)).and(not(lessThan(3))))
y should (be > (1) and not be <(3))
```

... and a lot more you can do with ScalaTest (e.g. use Scala pattern matching, assert what can/cannot compile, ...)

Answer (score 3):

Scalatest has build-in [matchers](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers). Also we use [expecty](https://github.com/pniederw/expecty). In some cases it's more concise and flexible than matchers (but it uses macros, so it requires at least 2.10 version of Scala).

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need Hamcrest with ScalaTest. Just mix in the `ShouldMatchers` or `MustMatchers` trait with your Spec. The difference between `Must` and `Should` matchers is you simply use `must` instead of `should` in assertions.

Example:

```
class SampleFlatSpec extends FlatSpec with ShouldMatchers {
     // tests
}
```